# How do I read this particular *.DAT file? (From Age of Empires 2)

Tags: java

Basic info: I have a DAT file from Age of Empires 2 Conquerer, the expansion pack (Forgotten Empires).

Question: I want to be able to read the contents of it. I tried using FileReader method and FileInputStream - ObjectInputStream. The first one gives me a weird output "ì½|÷óÿ—..." and the other one gives me this error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ECBD057C
Afaik, every DAT file is different and one needs to know how it was made.
I am noob at programming, so please excuse me if I haven't provided enough info.

More Details: Link to the file - http://www.4shared.com/file/6SkPpm6r/empires2_x1_p1.html
There are tools to read this file and edit it, however, I want to read it in a simple java program and extract what's inside of it. Tool to read it: http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11002

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possibly of interest -- https://github.com/fredreichbier/genie -- don't expect it to be trivial to work with, though. You will need to do a lot of heavy lifting.

Comment: You need to look up or reverse engineer the format of that file. Not all files contain human-readable text.

Comment: Reply to a few comments: The tool I have mentioned, its a specific .DAT file viewer for Age of Empires game. It reads the civilization, characters, etc. info from the file and displays it. One can also edit it and save it. I only wish to read it.
Why am I doing it?
Instead of creating an xml with all the info of the game, I wish to use the existing .DAT file and extract info from there. I don't know what would be more feasible, reading this DAT or creating my own XML.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it online, go to [NBT Editor](https://irath96.github.io/webNBT/). Drop the file there (from your File Explorer). The File may be in a readable format.